# Async Dependency Injection in View

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, dependency-injection, view

I'm trying to use the Repository pattern to manage my Service Access in a WPF application.

So basically I plan on using Ninject to inject my Singleton ServiceManager into each view that needs it.

I've built the ServiceManager so that each method call is asynchronous.

Now I've hit a snag. I'm creating a View that contains a DataGrid, populated by a slow, asychronous method. Currently I have the call in teh constructor but I obviously can't make the constructor asynchronous.

```
 public partial class OffersView : UserControl
{
    public OffersView(ISvcManager svcManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Offers.ItemsSource = await svcManager.GetLatestOffers();
    }
}
```

I can think of a couple of ways around this, eg I could separate the interface into fast methods and slow methods, and use async only for the slow ones with the synchronous fast methods being the ones called in Constructors. Not sure if this is the best approach to use though - and where would be the best place to call a long-running  method to populate the datagrid?

Alternatively, I  put a Wait() in there and only set the ItemSource after this completes. I REALLY don't like that approach.

So how should I be setting this one up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an asynchronous event handler like `Loaded`, which will allow for async calls.

For example

```
public partial class OffersView : UserControl {
    private readonly ISvcManager svcManager;
    public OffersView(ISvcManager svcManager) {
        this.svcManager = svcManager;
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += onLoaded;
    }

    private async void onLoaded(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Loaded -= onLoaded; // Unsubscribe to prevent repeated firing.
        Offers.ItemsSource = await svcManager.GetLatestOffers();
    }
}
```